# Is there a formula for $|\langle H\cup K\rangle|$, if $H$ and $K$ are nonempty subsets of a finite group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I know that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a finite group $G$, then $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$.

Is  there a formula for $|\langle H\cup K\rangle|$, if $H$ and $K$ are nonempty subsets of a finite group $G$?

Comment: You are looking for a formula which involve the cardinal of $H$ and $K$ and potentially the cardinal of a set combination between $H$ and $K$, right? For example, if $H$ is a singleton, and we take $H=K$, $|\langle H\cup K\rangle|$ is the order of the element.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo: That's correct!

Comment: Consider the case when *H* and *K* are subgroups of order 2 with an intersection of size 1. The size of the subgroup generated by *H* and *K* is an arbitrary even number ≥ 4.  I'm not sure what sort of formula you could be looking for under these circumstances.

Comment: Every countable group can be embedded in a $2$-generator group. In particular, $2$-generator groups can have arbitrarily large size. So if $H$ and $K$ are sets of size $1$, the size of $\langle H\cup K\rangle$ could potentially be as large as you want.

Comment: There is a lower bound, namely $\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$. From page 41, (Hungerford's book Algebra) $[H \vee K: H]\geq [K:H\cap K]$.